# Access SharePoint expanded properties

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, odata, powershell-3.0

I'm accessing a SharePoint lists has an associated stakeholder entity--I'm having difficultly accessing the stakeholder's properties.

The 'primary' content's properties are located on xpath `/feed/entry/content/properties/*`.  The stakeholder's properties are located on xpath `/feed/entry/link/inline/entry/content/properties/*`.

Assuming that I include the stakeholder's name in the odata query:

```
http://server/list/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TheList?$select=Id,Title,Stakeholder/Name&$expand=Stakeholder
```

How do I reference the stakeholder's properties when enumeration the feed's properties?

Using this code, the `Stakeholder.Name` property is not populated:

```
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials).entry.content.properties | Foreach {
  [PsCustomObject]@{
    Id=$_.Id."#text"; 
    Title=$_.Title; 
    StakholderName=$_.Stakeholder.Name;
  }
}
```

Do I need to populate a second `PsCustomObject` for the stakeholder, then merge the 'primary' data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is malformed since `$` symbol have to be escaped using single-quoted string literals, for example:

```
$url = "http://contoso.intranet.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TheList?`$select=Id,Title,Stakeholder/Name&`$expand=Stakeholder"
```

Then `Stakeholder` value could retrieved as demonstrated below:

```
$StakeholderValue = $data.link | where { $_.title -eq "Stakeholder" } | select -Property @{name="Name";expression={$($_.inline.entry.content.properties.Name)}}
```

**Modified example**

```
$url = "http://contoso.intranet.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TheList?`$select=Id,Title,Stakeholder/Name&`$expand=Stakeholder"

$data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/json;odata=verbose"  

$data  | Foreach {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
       Id = $_.content.properties.Id."#text"; 
       Title = $_.content.properties.Title; 
       Stakeholder = $_.link | where { $_.title -eq "Stakeholder" } | select -Property @{name="Name";expression={$($_.inline.entry.content.properties.Name)}}
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively i would propose to consider another approach. By default SharePoint 2010 REST service returns results in `xml` format. The idea is to return results in `json` format instead.

> Unfortunately neither [Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) nor
>   [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) could **not** be utilized for that purpose
>   since both of them contain a bug in PowerShell **3.0** according to
>   [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/757249/invoke-restmethod-accept-header).
>
> This particular bug prevents us to consume SharePoint REST services since 
>   since `Accept` header could not be specified and therefore results could not 
>   be returned in `json` format

Having said that, i would recommend to leverage [WebClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Below is demonstrated the same example that returns results in `JSON` format. Note that getting of `List Item` properties  become a way easier compared to the original example :

```
Function Execute-RequestJson()
{
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$Url,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [System.Net.ICredentials]$Credentials,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [bool]$UseDefaultCredentials = $True,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod]$Method = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod]::Get 
)

   $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
   if($Credentials) {
     $client.Credentials = $Credentials
   }
   elseif($UseDefaultCredentials){
     $client.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials 
   }
   $client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose")
   $client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")
   $data = $client.DownloadString($Url)
   $client.Dispose()
   return $data | ConvertFrom-Json
}





$url = "http://contoso.intranet.dev/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TheList?`$select=Id,Title,Stakeholder/Name&`$expand=Stakeholder"
$data = Execute-RequestJson -Url $url -UseDefaultCredentials $true

$data.d.results | Foreach {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
       Id = $_.Id; 
       Title = $_.Title; 
       Stakeholder = $_.Stakeholder.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, the OData queries work without escaping the `$`.  The examples at [OData](http://www.odata.org/) seem to suggest that this isn't necessary.

Comment: The `Execute-RequestJson` function is amazingly helpful--thanks!  Given that `ConvertFrom-Json` generates a `PsCustomObject`, the `Foreach` in your example seems unnecessary.